# mapnik and local tiff tiles

Tags: python, mapnik, geotiff

I have a local directory full of geotiff files which make up a map of the UK.

I'm using mapnik to render different images at various locations in the UK.

I'm wondering what is the best way to approach this?

I can create a single `RasterSymbolizer` then loop through the tiff directory and add each tiff as a seperate layer, then use mapniks `zoom_to_box` to render at the correct location.

But would this cause the rendering time to be unnecessarily slow? I have no information on how the tiles fit together (other than the data in each individual tiff of course).

I imagine there may be a way to setup some kind of vector file defining the tiff layout so I can quickly query that to find out which tile I need to render for a given bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

You can either generate a big tiff file from the original tiffs with `gdal_merge.py` (you can find it in the `python-gdal` package on Debian or Ubuntu) or create a virtual file that mixes them all with `gdal_merge-vrt`. This second option saves space but probably is slower.